# How do I get a self-addressed envelope from Canada to USA?

Tags: usa, canada, russian-citizens, mail

I had a consul general within the US verify my citizenship, and such verification must follow by a motivated conclusion (мотивированное заключение;) they claim that in order for me to receive it, I must send them a pre-paid self-addressed envelope.
I would like to use such conclusion in order to be able to apply for a passport at another consulate, without having to go through the whole process of citizenship verification all over again.

The problem: I'm visiting Canada and need to send them this self-addressed envelope from Canada, where I can't buy US stamps. Sending a self-addressed envelope from within the US of A, you just buy two stamps from USPS (one to send your envelope in, the other for the sender to get it back to you. Is it possible to send a self-addressed envelope from Canada to the United States, in order to get it back to Canada?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mail

Comment: But this is about travel!  Moreover, the envelope that I consider sending would be to the consulate general!

Comment: the site is more about travelling people, not travelling papers :)

Comment: i'm a travelling person, i need to get my papers in order in order to travel!

Comment: the thing is, eventhough this envelope will be sent to the consul, this question does not fit here. The core reason is about sending an envelope addressed to yourself..

Comment: Check out "international reply coupon", https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/atoz/irc.jsf

Comment: @mkennedy, that's interesting, however, it seems like it involves a mandatory trip to a post office, plus it costs 6 CAD; might as well be cheaper and less hassle-free to order a bunch of USPS stamps instead, since a letter from US to Canada likely costs less than 6 CAD?

Comment: cnst: @mkennedy's comment indicates how to handle return mail internationally, which answers your implied question.  Of course if you can purchase US stamps somehow, you can use them instead.  But which would be easier for you, to spend $6 at your local post office, or to arrange somehow to get US stamps while you are in Canada?

Comment: @phoog, it's not just a matter of price, but of satisfying the "please include a pre-paid return envelope", which wouldn't work with the 6 CAD coupon; it turns out, less than 3 USPS stamps are needed to mail a letter from US to Canada, so, it'll be both cheaper and more convenient to simply get a couple of US stamps prior to crossing into Canada

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed, all the while that the related questions, like http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26043/can-i-combine-two-french-stamps, remain alive and well?

Comment: @cnst why wouldn't the international reply coupon would satisfy the prepaid return envelope requirement?  Also, you can mail a stamp to Canada with one USPS stamp, if the face value is high enough.  Your question was closed because you didn't make it obviously about travel.  The question you linked to is posted by someone who is obviously not French and is about sending postcards from France; he is presumably therefore traveling.

Comment: @phoog, because by definition it's not a stamp, and cannot be affixed to an envelope (at least, based on the linked description); I don't live in Canada -- I'll only be travelling there for the summer, am I supposed to make that information part of the question?

Comment: @phoog, also, how exactly is it clear in http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26043/can-i-combine-two-french-stamps that the OP is not French, yet I am supposedly Canadian?  Travel has the most random policy on the off-topic questions!

Comment: @cnst, yes, the best questions on this site include residence and itinerary. Nels Beckman is not a French name, but of course that is not definitive proof that he's not French and even less persuasive on the question of residence. It's also worth noting that the question is about post cards, traditionally sent primarily by travelers. Also notice that the first comment to the question says it is off topic. It is a bit gray, granted. I don't have the rep to vote to reopen, but you can always re-ask the question and give it a more travel-oriented context.

Comment: @cnst on second thought, you should post a question about the larger problem you need to solve.  Why do think you need to send a stamped envelope to the consulate?  A consulate in the US normally cannot help you if you are in Canada; you need to apply to the country's consulate in Canada.  Are you trying to get a visa to go somewhere?  Tell the whole story, and you might get some useful advice.

Comment: @phoog, consulates don't just deal with visas; i already posted the other questions elsewhere, this really makes no sense that you close this, guys and gals -- why all the other identical questions remain open?!

Comment: @cnst I understand that consulates do other things that issue visas.  Regardless of the purpose of your business with the consulate, however, the general rule is that the consulate can only help you if you reside in its service area.  Do you reside in the US?  In general, though, what I am trying to make clear is that if you ask the question again, and explain the circumstances in sufficient detail so that it is clear why your question relates to travel, you are more likely to get a helpful response.

Comment: мотивированное заключение?! I think that not many of us can speak russian, can you please write only english

Comment: Added tag for russian-citizen ships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @mkennedy, *Canada Post* has a service called *International Reply Coupon*, which, as per their web-site, appears to be a one-size-fits-all that's valid in 191 countries (except for Taiwan), bearing a cost of 6,00 CAD.  https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/atoz/irc.jsf

However, the problem comes from the fact that, as its name suggests, it's *not an actual stamp*, but rather a *coupon*, which must be redeemed for a local stamp at a local post office in the country from which the reply mailing is to be made.  (The usage procedure is actually even documented as such right on their web-site.)

The above would go in contradiction with the requirement of having a "pre-paid envelope" -- after all, instead of attaching said coupon, it might as well be easier to provide a two 1 USD bills (see cost below), which, after all, can surely be be exchanged for adequate postage with more ease than having to deal with some sort of coupon most people have never heard of, and which appears to specifically require a visit to the Post Office.

As per [Can I combine two French stamps?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26043/can-i-combine-two-french-stamps), it generally costs only a couple of times more to post letters internationally than domestically.  As of 2015-05-09, one domestic first-class USPS stamp with a denomination value of FOREVER costs 0,49 USD (the FOREVER stamps will correspondingly and automatically increase in value if the price to post goes up), and such one stamp is sufficient for posting any small letter from any state to any other state.  As per http://ircalc.usps.com/MailServices.aspx?country=10054&m=1&o=2.0000, it currently costs 1,15 USD to mail a letter at or below 57 grams (2 ounces) from US to Canada, thus three such stamps at 1,47 USD should be sufficient to post internationally.

As such, the easiest solution would be to buy and affix three FOREVER stamps to the reply envelope, either within Canada, or before making a trip there.

Additionally, it seems like USPS also has the specifically designated **GLOBAL FOREVER** USPS stamps, too, which are currently valued at exactly 1,15 USD, and will always be sufficient for international postage.

Comment: this is a good debunking of the reply coupon, but really glosses over the part where you buy US stamps while you're in Canada. How would someone do that?

Comment: BTW, the Global Forever stamps seem to be a rather new thing -- introduced in 2013; and they actually let you mail 2 oz to Canada, whereas the weight is otherwise limited to 1 oz for other international locations.  https://about.usps.com/news/national-releases/2013/pr13_011.htm

Comment: @KateGregory, worst case, perhaps order them directly from https://www.usps.com/store/ ?  Google reveals that at certain point a few years ago, usps disabled international orders online, but you could still order over the phone or by fax.  I'm not sure if that's still accurate (I think international online ordering might be working again, especially now that they have Global Forever, which would indeed come in handy for self-addressed-stamped-envelope).